# Is it possible to link to the n-th character of a HTML page?

Tags: html, hyperlink

In a search component I plan to write, I would like to be able to point to specific places in a web page.

As an example, searching for `foo` would bring all instances of `foo` across all the pages of my site, to which I would like to provide a link (to the instance of the word `foo`, not to the page).

Is it possible to link to the *n*-th character of a HTML page?

Comment: @user202729: yes, I own the page but interleaving each word in the page with an anchor would be probably overkill (I though about that earlier but hope there is a better solution)

Comment: (you should specify that you own the site in the question. That's important)

Comment: Also: How do you expect "link to the n'th character" should behave? Scroll to the line which contains the character?

Answer (score 0):

Linking to a section of a page via the url only works when an element is referenced to by it's ID. So if you want to use the same behavior you will need to wrap each character found into an element with a unique Id when generating the page originating from the search results. I would not recommend using backend manipulation for this sort of thing but rather a frontend JS solution where in the url (or cookies, localstorage, etc) you specify the keyword and maybe the key (?keyword=foo&key=3). Then use JS to iterate through all instances and scroll to the desired instance. Here is a rough example of how the JS could look like:

```
var url = new URL(document.location.href);
var keyword = url.searchParams.get("keyword");
var key = url.searchParams.get("key");
$(window).scrollTop($("*:contains("+keyword+"):nth-child("+key+")").offset().top);
```

Keep in mind that this will scroll to the element that contains the word and not the exact line so if you have a large container with a lot of text this will still scroll to the top of that container. Nevertheless you could with JS further expand to make it scroll down to the line. And you would experience this issue if you were to reference the container via it's ID in the url anyway.